# Is it possible to use mysqli as database driver in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli

Configuration for database in laravel is:

```
'mysql' => [
'read' => [
    'host' => '192.168.1.1',
],
'write' => [
    'host' => '196.168.1.2'
],
'driver'    => 'mysql',
'database'  => 'database',
'username'  => 'root',
'password'  => '',
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => '',
],
```

It used PDO connection to connect mysql server.Is there any way to configure it to use mysqli instead of PDO driver. I am facing problem to read error message of running database using PDO driver in laravel. Is there any way to use mysqli?

Comment: `mysqli` is **not** a database driver. It's a library used to connect to MySQL. Fix your problem, don't change things randomly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to use mysqli?

No.

> I am facing problem to read error message

Just fix that problem.
If you think there is any problem with PDO, why not to ask a question regarding that problem?

Comment: actually problem is that PDO error message does not contain any proper message.It is hard to find actual error happens in sql.

It is very disappointing they does not support mysqli extension which have proper error message.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @SabbirAhmedSourove - PDO has the same messages as `mysqli`. Both libraries just pass along what MySQL reports back, even the source is similar. I don't think your issue is PDO and swapping to mysqli won't do you any good.

Comment: It's a valid question to ask.
It is a bit of a shortcoming that Laravel 8 (current version) does not support MySQLi out of the box.
The database.php file itself has a comment which says:

'All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities'.

Note however that there is the following package which purports to offer mysqli support.
https://github.com/shakahl/laravel-eloquent-mysqli

Comment: @omarjebari I am afraid this implementation of yours will be a disaster. That custom escaping function alone...